# Kendo ui Multi nested listview

Tags: kendo-ui, nested, kendo-listview

I java a similar nested json arrayobj, It may be from 1..X (not limited)

```
[{"id":"25","son": [
    {"id":"26", "son":  [
            {"id":"28","son":[],"message":"my message 1","creationDate":"2016-05-26"},
            {"id":"27","son":[],"message":"my message 2","creationDate":"2016-05-26"}
        ],
        "message":"my message 3","creationDate":"2016-05-26"}
    ],"message":"my message 4","creationDate":"2016-05-26"}
]
```

I nedd to display it using Kendo, I am using listviewm but it just list the firt item, not the son tag items.

I am trying to implement a forum control. Can you suggest a way to do it?. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, you won't be able to achieve what you want using a kendo listview because it wasn't designed to display hierarchical data (or nested data).

However, kendo do have other widgets that you can use to what you want to do.  I think the [TreeList](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/treelist/local-data-binding) is probably the one you are looking for.  In order to use that widget, you will have to modify the data from a nested format to a `id` / `parendId` format.  Using the sample data you provided, you should reformat the data like this:

```
var data = [
    { id:25,parentId: null, message:"my message 4",creationDate:"2016-05-26" },
    { id:26, parentId:25, message: "my message 3", creationDate:"2016-05-26"},
    { id:28, parentId:26, message":"my message 1",creationDate:"2016-05-26"},
    { id:27, parentId:26, message:"my message 2", creationDate:"2016-05-26"}
]
```

Depending on your need, you may also use a [TreeView](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/treeview/index) but this widget isn't designed to display multiple fields by default.  You can also use a grid with a custom detail template but that required extra code to handle the [detail grid template](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/detailtemplate) initialization.

Comment: Thank you, this will solve the problem, but I am using Kengo UI core, Do you recommend any alternative control in Kendo UI core?